# How to use Facebook APIs to show one's friends list to other visitors?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm able to fetch my friends list using [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (which requires me to log into my FB account) and I'm trying to show my friends list to other people visit my site.

I've tried using Twitter and its quite simple. `https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=codef0rmer` returns my followers ids.

Is that possible using Facebook API, If yes, How to do that?

Comment: I've created an APP ID on developer dashboard and used it to fetch friends list using FB.login and stuff. I think sharing code is not necessary as FB API documentation is in detail. Would you mind sharing some of the ways so my users can see my friends list once they visit the page?

Comment: No, I mean what have you tried to list friends? You say you know how to fetch your friends list with the facebook api... so what have you tried to do with it once you have it?

Comment: FB API generates access_token which I can pass to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=goes-here` which lists me the friends' name and ids but I can not pass the access_token manually as it expires after sometime. So I've used `FB.init() and FB.login()` functions to invoke the login window and then log into the facebook account which returns the access_token and then fetch the friends data.

Comment: Listing *your* friends is against [facebook's privacy policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). Don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the /friends connection you need a valid access token for the current session. This means you can't access this connection for other users

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/

This means that unless you get a users friends and store them in your database, you won't be able to do this. ( Unless you use longer living access tokens (I say longer living as offline access is being deprecated)

Saying this, I'm not sure if you are allowed to store this information. I know friendslists aren't allowed to be shown to other users so this is potentially dangerous territory on facebook TOS. The privacy policy is here https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ but I think this is something you may need to clarify with Facebook directly as it looks like a slightly grey area